# Why the parent list object's property got update when I deal with new list

Tags: javascript

I have two list:

```
parentList = [{ name: "Item1", flag: true }, { name: "Item2", flag: true }, { name: "Item3", flag: true }];

childList = [];
```

I am pushing a clicked item from parentList into a childList array,

Which works fine, but when I remove an item from childList and if I change the property of parentList:

On parentList List clicked:

```
this.childList.push(item);
```

On childList remove clicked:

```
var index = this.childList.indexOf(item);
this.childList.splice(index, 1)
item.flag = false;
```

The item got removed from child List but when I console the values of parentList then it gives me `false` for a flag key.

Unable to understand why it changing the property's value of `parentList`?

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rwpj4h)

Comment: Probably because item is copied by reference?  If I'm understanding your query, you don't want to 'mutate' the parent list - if so, you'll need to clone the item so when you change it, it doesn't update (mutate) the original.

Comment: @PhilCooper Thanks bit more detailed? Or document to get the difference?

Answer (score 2):

It changes property on parentList because you are passing an object's reference around.

A reference points to the same object, it's not a copy.

You could copy the object and put that copy in the second list if that's what you intend to

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item))
```

Answer (score 2):

When you push the item in the child list, you're inserting the same object.
When you do:

`var object1 = new Object();
 var object2 = object1;`

You're not copying the object into the other variable, you're copying it's reference, that is a sort of address used to locate the object in the memory of the computer.
So because they have the same reference, the two variables lead you to the same object in memory.

The same happens when you take an object from a list and push it in another list.
You're taking the reference, and then you put the reference in the other list.

So you need to pass two completely different objects. You can create a copy of the object that you are passing using:

- `let newObj = Object.assign({}, yourObj)`, that basically takes all the properties of 'youObj', and copy them in the new object '{}', and then returns this new object. But this works only if the properties are not nested!
- `let newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(yourObj))`, that creates a JSON string of the object and then use the same string to re-create the object as new one (JSON is a string format to represent Javascript objects).

Comment: Ok, only dealing with a list and object it copy by reference?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Basically everything that is not a number, a string or a boolean, in Javascript is seen like an object. Lists (Arrays in Javacript) are objects too.

Comment: function too are passed by reference. basically everything you can put in a var that is not a primitive is passed around as reference.